# Доступ к сайту с определённого диапазона IP PHP

Tags: php

Имеется страница, которую можно посещать только с определённого диапазона IP:

```
185.71.76.0/27
185.71.77.0/27
77.75.153.0/25
77.75.154.128/25
2a02:5180:0:1509::/64
2a02:5180:0:2655::/64
2a02:5180:0:1533::/64
2a02:5180:0:2669::/64
```

Код для одного IP выглядит так:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']!='192.168.0.1')exit();
```

Как сделать тоже самое для огромного диапазона IP, указанного выше?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594112 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951061

Comment: Это можно сделать в Apache / Nginx зачем в пых тащить?